# html in google maps tooltip

Tags: google-maps

i have a custom google map with some markers on. To display some content inside the text balloon when you click the marker i use html. Simple stuf like `<p>` and `<b>`

But when you hover over the marker it just displays the full html.
Like

```
 <p>some text</p><p>some other <b>text</b></p>
```

is this normal? Or what can i do about it?

Answer (score 0):

The GMarker title element does not supports html Strings.

Comment: is there a way to use a different string for the marker and the text balloon?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass some HTML in when the marker is clicked. See the [openInfoWindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker.openInfoWindow) function.